# NSTableView get what cell is being edited with keyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

When I click with the mouse I can get the cell position with `myTableView.clickedRow` and `myTableView.clickedColumn`.

However if I click on the first cell and then I press "Tab" key on my keyboard, the selection will stay on `row = 0` and `column = 0`.

Is there a way to track the row and column index when changing cell with keyboard ?

Comment: Do you want to be notified when the focused cell changes or do you want to get the row and column of the focused cell or do you want to know if the focused cell is being edited?

Comment: I want to get the row and column of the focused cell

Comment: Be careful here. Cell based NSTableView - cell gets focus. View based NSTableVIew - view won't get focus. By pressing tab you are moving focus to elements that responds to key events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a text field in a cell is focused then the first responder is the field editor of the text field. Use `row(for:)` and `column(for:)` of `NSTableView` to get the row and column.

```
if let view = window.firstResponder as? NSView {
    let column = tableView.column(for: view)
    let row = tableView.row(for: view)
}
```